# How many simple cycles can a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges have?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, cycles

I am mainly interested in the smallest number of simple cycles a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges must have.
For example, if $m\le n-1$, this number is $0$, then if $n\le m \le 3(n-1)/2$, it is $m-n$, then after a while it starts to grow exponentially with $m$.
What is known about this function?

Comment: If the rate of growth accelerates as more edges are added, it can't literally become exponential until we are only $O(n\log n)$ edges short of a complete graph. Is that inconsistent with what you know?

Comment: @Brendan: To be honest, I did not spend too much time thinking about this, it was just obvious that the end becomes exponential. I am more interested in the beginning, like the function in Tony's answer, except that I want the minimum number of cycles.

Comment: I know what the domain and the range is but it is so had some time but I can get it done.(((:

Answer (score 5):

To supplement Igor's answer, here is some more information on the *maximum* number of cycles  a graph on $n$ vertices with $m$ edges can have.  I apologize that this does not answer your question.  Entringer and Slater considered this problem in their paper *On the Maximum Number of Cycles in a Graph*.

Let $G$ be a simple connected graph with $m$ edges and $n$ vertices.  It is useful to re-parametrize by letting $d=m-n+1$, and defining $\psi(d)$ to be the maximum number of cycles of a graph with $m-n+1=d$.  They observed that since $d$ is the dimension of the cycle space of $G$, $\psi(d) \leq 2^d-1$.  On the other hand, they showed that the Möbius ladders imply that $\psi(d) \geq 2^{d-1}+d^2-3d+3$. Using exhaustive computer search they also determined $\psi(d)$ for all $d \leq 8$, and conjectured that the lower bound is essentially the right answer for $\psi(d)$.

Answer (score 2):

For planar graphs there are recent (exponential) bounds, as in [Buchin et al, 2007.](http://cs.uni-muenster.de/u/schulz/papers/counting-cycles.pdf)

Comment: This paper is also about the most number of cycles a graph might have. It is also of interest, but here the number of edges is not given.

Comment: @domotorp true, but for planar graphs there is an implied upper bound (linear in the number of vertices), and the explicit examples in the paper provide lower bounds.

Comment: @Igor: How does an example provide a lower bound?  It can only provide a lower bound on the maximum.